# Different Mutex attributes

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Is function `pthread_mutexattr_settype` different then  `pthread_mutexattr_setkind_np` ?
I got random output, and i'm not sure...
Im trying to see whats happend if i type Normal, Error check and Recursive type of mutex...

```
switch(atoi(argv[1])){
    case 1:
      puts("ERROR CHECK");
      pthread_mutexattr_settype(&m_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);
      break;
    case 2:
      puts("RECURSIVE");
      pthread_mutexattr_settype(&m_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
      break;
    default:
      puts("NORMAL");
      pthread_mutexattr_settype(&m_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL);
      break;  
  }

puts("Before 1 lock");
pthread_mutex_lock(&data->mutex);
test_errno("1 lock");
puts("          After 1 lock");

puts("Before 2 lock");
pthread_mutex_lock(&data->mutex);
test_errno("2 lock");
puts("      After 2 lock");

puts("Before 1 unlock");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&data->mutex);
test_errno("1 unlock");
puts("      After 1 ulock");

puts("Before 2 unlock");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&data->mutex);
test_errno("2 unlock");
puts("      After 2 ulock");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the sourcecode (ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/sources/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release/pthread_mutexattr_setkind_np.c) you will find the following:

```
int
pthread_mutexattr_setkind_np (pthread_mutexattr_t * attr, int kind)
{
  return pthread_mutexattr_settype (attr, kind);
}
```

The two methods also also have the exact same signature except for their names, so you can rely on their being aliases of each other. The manual page https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutexattr_init.html also states that `pthread_mutexattr_setkind_np` is an alias for `pthread_mutexattr_settype`.